# How to create canocical from controller in grails?

Tags: grails

In grails, I have a link like /myapp/questions/all

The all is a parameter (all, replied, ...) passed to my controller.

I have a form to search question depending of type : in all, in replied, ...
In the search form, I have an hidden field to pass parameter.

But the url displayed is /myapp/questions/ ans not /myapp/questions/all

So I tried with url : url="[action:'question', controller:'mycontroller', params:['monparam':'${mavariable}']]"

but it's not working.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        name nameOfTheMapping: "/question/$para/" {
            controller = "mycontroller"
            action = "question"
        }
    ...
```

Then you can access the mapping by:

```
<a href='${createLink(mapping: 'nameOfTheMapping', params: [para: para.encodeAsUrl()])}' title='test'>Test</a>
```

The above code is created in my taglib, so it maybe a little different if you want to use it in a view.

Comment: Yes, but it's working fine with a link but not with a form :
<g:form url="controller:mycontroller, action:myaction, params:['myparam':'${myparam}']"> ... </g:form>
I think that's not a problem with my url mapping but with the form tag that encode the ${myparam}

Comment: @Jonathan: I haven't seen that usage before. Often, I dispatch the form directly to the controller/action using its data: <g:form  controller="myController" action="myAction"  name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @Jonathan: after processing at the action, you can redirect to any page you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question, but it seems you are not following the grails convention.  the url is of the form

```
/app/controller/action
```

so grails is interpreting the 'all' part of your url as the action to invoke on the questions controller (what I got from your 'link like /myapp/questions/all').

Where I got confused was with your url specification.

```
 url="[action:'question', controller:'mycontroller', params:['monparam':'${mavariable}']]"
```

Based on that, you should have a controller called 'mycontroller', with an action called 'question' on it.  The url you will see in the browser would be

> /app/mycontroller/question?monparam:whatever

See [here](http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Creating+Controllers+and+Actions) for details on controllers in general.

Comment: I implemented in the UrlMapping : 
"/myapp/question/$myparam" { controller=mycontroller action=myaction}. In the g:link, I can do g:link controller=mycontroller action=myaction params=['myparam:myvalue'] and the result is /myapp/question/myvalue but it's not working with the form. If I add the params=[myparam:${myvar}] the url displayed is /myapp/question/${myvar}

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy` and create a mapping to the controller that omits the action. (since you're handling this all within one action)

something like

```
"/questions/$question_type" (controller: 'questions', action: 'your_action')
```

where "your_action" is the name of the action that is processing these requests.

Then in `QuestionsController.groovy`:

```
def your_action = {
    // use question_type as needed
    def questions = Questions.findByQuestionType(params.question_type)
    // etc.
}
```

You can do a variety of things to affect the mapping of urls to requests, check out the [UrlMapping section in the Grails User Guide.](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.4%20URL%20Mappings)

Comment: Your right and I use the UrlMapping but with the form it's not working. See my comment on the previous answer

Comment: your params should be something like `<g:link ... params="[myparam: myvar]"/>`. You shouldn't need the extra expression notation '${' and '}'.

Comment: I tried it but the content is not displayed but it's the variable name but only in for tag not in g:link